# Are sucralose ("Splenda") and all other chlorinated hydrocarbons toxic?

Tags: nutrition, toxicology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long term effects of sucralose](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5793/long-term-effects-of-sucralose)

Is it true that sucralose is the only chlorinated hydrocarbon we eat and that chlorinated hydrocarbons are inherently toxic?  (I realize the source of these claims is the pro-sugar brigade)

Comment: Could you please link to some relevan claim you are skeptical of (and explain why you are)?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)! We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. I hope the references will show if simply demonstrating that edible fish contains contains chlorinated hydrocarbons (presumably as contaminants) and hence sucralose isn't the only source, will refute the claim.

Comment: Technically, *everything* is toxic in sufficiently high doses (and pretty much everything is nontoxic in sufficiently low doses).